# ML Classification - My Accuracy is too low

Tags: python, machine-learning, classification

i'm at the very beginning of the Machine Learning with Python, I have created a dataset which has about 2k instances. Those datas are game datas, but it is just a stupid game that i've created in few hours to make a prediction with it's datas. I'll give some instances for you guys to understand how my dataset is. 
Game is pretty is i am creating a position between 0 and 2000 and a number 1 to 10. those are random things and i think that if i know last number and current number maybe i can predict next label.

but my accuracy was very bad (see in below):

```
                               mean()   Std()
LogisticRegression:            0.480933 (0.035875)
MLPClassifier:                 0.441474 (0.029023)
LinearDiscriminantAnalysis:    0.481954 (0.035140)
QuadraticDiscriminantAnalysis: 0.487177 (0.026079)
KNeighborsClassifier:          0.450221 (0.022375)
DecisionTreeClassifier:        0.421849 (0.028847)
GaussianNB:                    0.488129 (0.030311)
RandomForrest:                 0.469209 (0.029449)
AdaBoostClassifier:            0.458311 (0.039868)
```

Dataset Snip: There is also last_number but it didn't fit the page so i delete it but it was there.

```
last_number    last_pos   current_number   current_pos    Label
 2              0.0          9             320.5           1
 7            320.5         10            1879.5           1
 9           1879.5          7               6.5           1
10              6.5          8             170.5           0
 3            170.5          4            2000.0           0
```

I think classification is not the way, i should work with on. so what kind of techniques i can use for my dataset, i mean maybe regression, neural network or something can help my issues :)

Comment: is there *any* relation between label and position & number? Or everything here is just a random thing taken from uniform distribution?

Comment: Yes there is some relation between last and current number, Positions are created by last games position but also random. it can be said there is position's range between the label but i cant clearly say that because dataset is too large

Comment: Given the `last_number` and `last_pos`, how _exactly_ do you generate the `current_number`, `current_pos`, and `Label`?

Comment: For a clear answer there is relation between last and current position like if last position range is 1500 so it will 500 in next game, but i didnt decide that i notice that after i look at the dataset.

Comment: You said you created the dataset. Don't you know _how_ you created it?

Comment: Game is web based with php, i crawled the datas so i also create the dataset, i start crawling after few hours i notice it :) i mean everything is random but in dataset  it is like it has a pattern or so i dont know yet :)

Comment: Not sure if you still care about this but your results are worse than guessing :). Are you able to provide a full data set and are these all of the possible features you've included. It's not a lot to go on.